# How to remove/hide place for icon of menu item android

Tags: android, kotlin, icons, menuitem, bottomnavigationview

I am newer in android
I am using bottomNavigationView, and in menu i don't need to use icons, because of this, an empty space appeared. I've tried decrease height of menu and of bottomNavigationView but nothing is helped.
[It is my BottomNavigationView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMvFh.png)

[Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KR7E.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruNzd.png)

Any links, comments, explanations will hepl me

Comment: The menu items you posted has icons in it how did you remove the icons?

Comment: @oziomajnr, yes, i need text only menu

Comment: Hi Aden, If you find a solution you can post an answer accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found decision

added in my build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:2.0.4'
implementation "com.android.support:design:28.0.0"
```

Changed BottomNavigationView to BottomNavigationViewEx

and in my Fragment

```
val bottomNavigationView = requireView().findViewById<BottomNavigationViewEx>(R.id.bottom_navigation_view_ex)
bottomNavigationView.setIconVisibility(false)
```